# Laravel 8 Migrations - How can I create instances of a Model, and add it a value, when a database is being created with Migrations?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, database-migration

I am a beginner to Web Development and I am facing an issue with a problem that seems rather simple.

I am trying to insert values immediatly after a database is created with migrations with Laravel 8.
This is the my code:

```
Schema::create('templates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();

    for ($i = 0; $i != 3; $i++) {
        $template = new Template;
        switch ($i) {
            case 0:
                $template->name = 'Template 1';
                break;
                    
            case 1:
                $template->name = 'Template 2';
                break;
    
            case 2:
                $template->name = 'Template 3';
                break;
        }
    }

});
```

How can I achieve the result that I want?

Comment: why don't you use seeders?

Comment: Look at seeders, or just move the `for` outside of the `Schema::create` so you create the table, then run your code. And add a `$template->save()` at the end.

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank the table is still empty.

Comment: @NickOlder and add a `$template->save()` after the switch.

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank yes, i forgot about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not saving a resource to the database with that code. You're only creating an instance of a `Template` object and setting the `name` property. You'd have to call `save()` on it afterwards to save it to the database.

Try calling your model code outside of (after) your `Schema::create` call.

Also, this is not part of your question, but you could simplify that create functionality in a number of ways. Here's one:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection; // at the top of the file

...

Schema::create('templates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Collection::times(3, fn ($number) => Template::create(['name' => 'Template ' . $number]);
```

#### Note

Creating `Template` objects like this will only work if you have added the `name` property to the `$filllable` array for the model, AND if there are no other fields in that table (auto-incrementing primary keys excluded) that require non-null values (obviously not relevant in this case, but something to consider when using mass-assignment).

Here's some more information from the laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-times

Answer (score 0):

you should use a constant seeder.
see this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/set-default-information-in-laravel-5-database?signup)